# Any other way to figure out user country on iphone except using NSLocaleCountryCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to restrict some contents of my app based on user country (from where app is currently being accessed). I am aware of `NSLocaleCountryCode` but the issue is that user can go ahead and change the location used/returned by `NSLocaleCountryCode` in iPhone settings.

Is there any other way to figure out user's country?

Answer (score 2):

Get the latitude and longitude of the user and found out the country. It will give the exact result.